# Angular Pipe giving value(brand) undefiend

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-pipe

Hi I am trying to create an angular filter for checkbox. But in console it is saying that `brand is undefined`. What could be the problem -

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'selectBrand'
})
export class SelectBrandPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(brand: any, brandType?: any): any {
    console.log('brand', brandType);
    if (!brandType || brandType.length === 0) return brand;
    return brand.filter(brandName => 
    brandType.includes(brandName.companyName));
  }
}
```

The filter where I have used -

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of prod.product | selectBrand: brandType">
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Added -

My shop component -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../services/product.service';
import { Products } from '../data/products';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { PricerangePipe } from '../pipes/pricerange.pipe';
import { PricerangeMaxPipe } from '../pipes/pricerange-max.pipe';
import { SelectBrandPipe } from '../pipes/select-brand.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shop',
  templateUrl: './shop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shop.component.scss']
})
export class ShopComponent implements OnInit {
productList: Products[];
productListShow = [];
minPrice: number = 0;
maxPrice: number = 1100;
brandName: string;

constructor(private productservice: ProductService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.productList = this.productservice.getProducts();
    this.productListShow = this.productList;


this.activatedRoute.params
    .subscribe(params => {
      if (params.type === 'jeans') {
         this.productListShow = this.productList.filter(product=> product.productCat == 'Jeans');
         console.log('productListShow');
      } else if(params.type === 'shirts') {
         this.productListShow = this.productList.filter(product=> product.productCat == 'Shirts');
      } else if(params.type === 'watches') {
         this.productListShow = this.productList.filter(product=> product.productCat == 'Watches');
      }
    });

 }

}
```

Some of the code I have removed from component, as it was not related to this issue

My console log screen shot - 
[image]

Comment: Can you post the component that uses your pipe?

Comment: You mean `console.log('brand', brandType);` right? Have you confirm that brandType is not undefined ?

Comment: hi @sugarme, I have added the component please let me know if you need html and json code as well

Comment: hi @NuruSalihu I am not sure how can I find out

Comment: I can't see 'prod' variable declared in component but you used in template. Is that productListShow?

Comment: From here `<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of prod.product | selectBrand: brandType">` i can see you pass brandType as a parameter to your pipe. But in your component.ts i don't see the defination of brandType. Where then is brandType comoing from ? If its not defined ofcourse it will be undefine in the pipe as well. Where is the brandType definiation ?

Comment: Can you post the whole component ? What you pasted above hardly as any relevance here.

Comment: Are you sure that your service provides Products synchronously? If not, you should use async strategy to get your products ready before chaining them with your pipe

Comment: Can you share the console error screenshot as well

Comment: Hi @ShashankVivek please find the console screen shot in the question

Comment: hi @NuruSalihu I have included the full component